# Nested while loop to draw pattern

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Hi I'm wondering on how to use a nested loop to draw this pattern on the output

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
#      #
#       #
```

I found out how to do it in a loop without nested, but I am curious as to how to draw this using a nested while loop.

```
while r < 7:
    print("#{}#".format(r * " "))
    r = r + 1
```

Comment: You can do this with nested `while` loops, but a single `for` loop will suffice. If you're trying to wrap your head around nested loops, you'd be better served finding a problem to which they are a natural solution

Comment: Why add complexity with a nested `while` loop if you can do it more simply with a single `while`?

Comment: The assignment wants me to use a nested loop, no idea why. I can just use a single loop :S

Comment: If the solution works for you , you should accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to your actual question: using two nested while loops.

```
num_spaces_wanted = 0
while num_spaces_wanted < 7:
    print('#', end='')
    num_spaces_printed = 0
    while num_spaces_printed < num_spaces_wanted:
        print(' ', end='')
        num_spaces_printed += 1
    print('#')
    num_spaces_wanted += 1
```

As the print statements show, this is for Python 3.x. Adjust them for 2.x or add the line `from __future__ import print_function` to get the 3.x style printing.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do this in python
You don't need a nested loop.

**Edit** With two loops

```
#!/bin/python
import sys

n = int(raw_input().strip())
for i in xrange(n):
    sys.stdout.write('#')
    for j in xrange(i):
        sys.stdout.write(' ')
    sys.stdout.write('#')
    print
```

Comment: Why not just `xrange(n)`?

Comment: But OP specifically asks for nested while loops.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other answers which already correctly answer the question, but I think the following does so in a conceptually more simple way, and it should make it easier to learn from.

```
spaces = 0

while spaces < 8:
    to_print = "#"

    count = 0
    while count < spaces:
        to_print += " "
        count += 1

    to_print += "#"

    print to_print
    spaces += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient solution for a nested loop:

```
#!/bin/python

n = int(raw_input().strip())
for i in xrange(n):
    string = "#" + i * " " + "#"
    print string
    for -1 in xrange(n)
    # Do nothing
```